# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, log4j

I have a java web service deployed using tomcat. I am trying to write to the event viewer from java using log4j and NTEventLog dlls. I added "NTEventLogAppender.dll" into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin which is on my system path and registered it using the regsvr32 command.

I am having the following exception:

```
5263 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet  - org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Native Method)
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:79)
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:49)
    at packagecct1.Procurements.<init>(Procurements.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils$8.run(Utils.java:768)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.createServiceObject(Utils.java:765)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.makeNewServiceObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:245)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.getTheImplementationObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:282)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

log4j.properties:

```
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CA,NTEventLog 
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CA        

#Console Appender 
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n 

#File Appender 
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.FA.File=sample.log 
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

#Event Log Appender
log4j.appender.NTEventLog=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.NTEventLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NTEventLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.NTEventLog.source=ESBWebServices


# Set the logger level of File Appender to WARN 
log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = WARN
```

java code:

```
    System.loadLibrary("NTEventLogAppender");

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    NTEventLogAppender eventLogAppender = new NTEventLogAppender();
    eventLogAppender.setSource("ESBWebServices");

    eventLogAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%m"));
    eventLogAppender.activateOptions();
    logger.addAppender(eventLogAppender);

    logger.info("Hello World!");
```

Kindly note am using eclipse as an IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Log4J v1.2.17 only includes the pre-build amd64 compatible DLL (called NTEventLogAppender.amd64.dll.  When the `NTEventLogAppender` runs it looks at the System architecture (`System.getProperty("os.arch"`)) and then attempts to load either the amd64, ia64, or x86 version of the DLL which must be in a file called: NTEventLogAppender..dll.

Instead of just shipping with all the possible DLLs Apache give you the src to be able to build your own DLL for your target architecture in src/ntdll of the distribution.  There are two ways to build it, one using MinGW, and the other using the MS Visual Studio build tools.  I used the latter to build my own DLL by running the command `ant msbuild` in this directory.

It was not a painless process and i had to hunt around for the various libs and header files as well as the rc, mc, cl, and link exes required to build it.  Finally, i had to rename the built DLL to `NTEventLogAppender.x86.dll` and put it on my path in order to get it picked up.

Anyway, because i couldn't find a place to upload this DLL file i created a Gist of the base64 hash of the file here: https://gist.github.com/alpian/5614954.  Take the text and put it through any of the many free online base64 converters and save it to the appropriately named DLL file and you're done.  This may be easier than building it yourself, maybe not! :)

Comment: thank you for this  answer but a can u send me the dll ? karim.eltel@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @alpian's reply, there *is* actually a NTEventLogAppender.dll, compiled for x86 in the log4j-1.2.17.zip, and log4j will load this successfully if it's on the library path. However, it appears to have been incorrectly compiled, and doesn't include the C functions for the required JNI methods, which leads to the particular UnsatisfiedLinkError mentioned in the OP.

As an alternative to compiling, you can roll back to 1.2.16, which seems to have a working DLL.